# Issue with Div Centering

Tags: css, html, center

I have a div with the following CSS:

```
.glyphicon-arrow-right  {
    font-size:25px;
    margin-top:22.66%;
    margin-left:5%;
    color: #414141;
}
```

set inside a div with CSS

```
.forwardbutton  {
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    border-radius:50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1.75px solid #414141;
    opacity: .3;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

When I resize on a computer screen, the arrow sits directly in the center. However, when I view the div on other devices (tablet, netbook/ phone) the arrow is not centered, with a height noticeable higher than it should be.

I was wondering if anyone could identify the issue. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: HTML

```
<a href="work.html">
    <div class="forwardbutton">
        <div class="front glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Post your HTML too. Also, a jsFiddle.net example might be helpful.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? Vertically centered or horizontally centered? The margins on your glyphicon look suspicious